# Can someone translate this C++ into AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, square-root

This code stores the sqrt() of the numbers from 0 to 4095 in a table, and I would like to translate it into Actionscript 3.

```
unsigned short int_sqrt_x1024[4096];

for (int i=0; i<sizeof(int_sqrt_x1024)/sizeof(int_sqrt_x1024[0]); i++)
int_sqrt_x1024[i] = (int)(sqrtf((float)i + 0.5f) * 1024.0f);
```

I've done it halfway, but the 'sizeof' parts got me, I havent got a clue what to do with those!

So based on your suggestions I've come up with this, what do you think???:

```
var int_sqrt_x1024:Vector.<uint> =  new Vector.<uint>(4096,true)
for (var i:int = 0; i < int_sqrt_x1024.length; i++)
int_sqrt_x1024[i] = Math.sqrt( i + 0.5) * 1024;
```

Comment: You should ignore the sizeof code, that's an ugly way to do it in C++ in the first place.  The loop is just iterating 4096 times, so just replace the sizeof terms with i < 4096

Answer (score 1):

You can find the definition of `sizeof` [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). To the best of my knowledge, there is no analogous operator in AS3. I have never encountered anything like it in documentation, and searches reveal nothing.

In fact, the closest thing I can find to it is the completely unrelated [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html), which I can guarantee *would not* achieve the same end, as one is an advanced data type and the other is an operator. Their usages aren't even similar.

I am curious, what is the goal of this code? Perhaps there is another way to achieve the same end. (And apparently from reading comments, there is actually a better way.)

EDIT: See Basic's comment below...there may be something similar.

Comment: Interestingly, this page http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-576ba64d124318d7189-7fff.html seems to imply there's a `getSize()`? Although I agree, just doing loop `0<=i<4096` would be simpler

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't provide a translation since I don't know Actionscript, but I think this will help you out too:

The C `sizeof`-Operator returns the size in bytes of its argument. This is not something you need to concern yourself with in a "managed" language like Actionscript. What the C code you posted (I don't really see anything in it that would necessarily make it C++) does, is iterating through the loop (`size_of_the_array_in_bytes` / `size_of_one_array_element_in_bytes`) times. In your case, that complicated expression would simply evaluate to 4096.

In other worlds, make a loop that executes the store of the square root 4096 times.

---

The C-code you're using as a basis seems to be pretty poorly written. I can't seem to find a reason one would use such a complicated, verbose and unreadable way to fill a simple lookup table. IMO, it should be something like this:

```
#define LOOKUPTABLE_LENGTH 4096
unsigned short int_sqrt_x1024[LOOKUPTABLE_LENGTH];

for (int i=0; i<LOOKUPTABLE_LENGTH; i++)
    int_sqrt_x1024[i] = (int)(sqrtf((float)i + 0.5f) * 1024.0f);
```

Much more readable, no?

Comment: yeah that seems much more reasonable, too bad I dont really know much of C/C++
I've got the code off from here btw:
http://www.geisswerks.com/ryan/FAQS/fast_int_sqrt.html

Comment: Hmm, the overall code there appears much more reasonable to me. Maybe the author just doesn't like defines and global constants? They should be used for this exact purpose though. And since I'm not allowed to comment on your question, I'm putting this here: the AS3 translation in your edit seems ok. I think you can go with that.